# Batch import of DEM's with various file types

Tags: qgis, dem, batch

I am trying to import from folder called DTM many inputs, (each of file type SOS, TWF, TIF, XML, OVR). I have tried almost every different way of adding layer,  nothing seems to work.

How can I import these type of files, if possible at all?

Comment: The file you want to open is the .TIF (the other are compagnon file), you should be able to add it either by using the data source manager browser and navigate to your file or by choosing the "add raster layer" and select your TIF file. If that didn't work you need to give more detail on what went wrong

Comment: Try drag-and-drop: from the file explorer of your operating systems, drag the files you want to open to the QGIS window. QGIS will open those files it can open.